# Instalação do Material Design

Tags: javascript, html, css, npm, material-design

Eu estou tentando fazer um projeto utilizando o 
[Material Design](https://material.io/components/web/)

Eu tenho o NPM instalado mas, não estou conseguindo instalar.
Eu entro na pasta do projeto e no terminal digito:

```
npm install --save material-components-web
```

Aparecem as seguintes mensagens:

```
+ material-components-web@0.32.0
updated 1 package in 4.986s
```

Eu referencio no meu arquivo de teste:

```
 "node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.css"

 "src="node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.js"
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: seguiu esses passos? https://material.io/components/web/docs/getting-started/ você tem as dependências instaladas?

Comment: @HebertdeLima Obrigado! Era isto mesmo! A página é meio confusa. A gente entra na página principal e escolhe o tipo de design. Não explica sobre estas dependências. Mais uma vez agradeço.

Comment: é sempre bom procurar pela documentação, parece bobagem mas ler o "manual" economiza horas quebrando a cabeça! rs